# Fragment activity exception: cannot perform this action after onsaveinstance called

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I've got the below crash dump from google play.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1527)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:599)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:178)
   at com.myapp.activities.ActivityManageContacts.onBackPressed(ActivityManageContacts.java:265)
   at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2465)
   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2646)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2716)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:533)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:254)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2276)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4038)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4000)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3615)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3581)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3698)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3589)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3755)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3615)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3581)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3589)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3615)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3581)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3731)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3892)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
   at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

My activity extended from FragmentActivity. I just override onBackPressed method in my activity. In this onBackPressed method, super method(super.onBackPressed) is calling. In that super method, fragments states are accessed. How to avoid this crash.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to override **onSavedInstanceState** into your fragment like this

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}
```

than use **CommitAllowingStateLoss()** instead of **commit()**

Comment: It will affect my fragment's UI state.